# How do the App knows whether the user did a Facebook POST or DISCARD

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook

In my Android Game,I am using Facebook SDK to share the open graph story. When the user sees the sharin screen. The user may post it or it can be discarded by pressing the back button.

After the user returs to the game, I need to know whether the user has posted the story or discarded it. I need to reward the user if he shares it.

For now, I use the below code to know the status. The code reaches onSuccess() even for POST or DISCARD.

### Code

```
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            //always gets called
            socialShareType=FB_SHARE;
            System.out.println("socialShareType in FB onSuccess : " + socialShareType);
            Log.d("FBshare", "Share done Successfully");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("FBshare", "Share cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("FBshare", "Share error");

        }

    });
```

Comment: It should not reach onSuccess() for discarding.

Comment: rewarding the user in any way for sharing is not allowed, you MUST read the platform policy before creating any app.

Comment: Rewarding with the virtual currency which can be used to buy IAP. This is already done is app like candy crush. Whenever the invite friends the user get lifes. I am trying something similar to that..  Is that a policy breachment

Comment: @luschn Also I know this is not welcomed in App Store. Is it the same in Google play store

Comment: I do not find such policy in play store. It would be a great help if you could point me the policy

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: it does not matter if anyone else is doing something that is not allowed. and candy crush is using app requests, that is completely different to sharing and only possible for games with a canvas implementation.

Comment: those are facebook rules btw, so as long as you are using facebook stuff in any way, you have to accept them. does not matter if your app is in the app store, or in the google play store or elsewhere.

Comment: 4.5: Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions - rewarding a user for sharing would be incentivizing > not allowed. this is subject of hundreds of threads already, and the reason why it is so hard to get a clear callback.

Comment: So Rewarding the FB sharing or invite is not acceptable. Hence I dropped the plan to reward it.  I planned to reward only the G+ share and google App invite. Hope this work !.  Thanks @luschn for your timely advice.